# Injecting third party script on Nuxt - cookie handling on ssr( issue)

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

So I am working on my first Nuxt web app, which is supposed to target the server. However I fully don't understand the management of ssr and I am not sure if my issue is related to that.

So I am importing an script for third party service for cookies. The problem that I have is that ... based on their [documentation](https://support.cookiefirst.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011433437-Install-Add-the-cookie-banner-to-your-website-or-shop) I needed to include the script on the website in order to have:

- First: A pop up being triggered when the page loads
- Second: on the "cookie-policy" page, I just need to include a div with an id, which will make automatically load a content with the policy, coming from the service.

So at the beginning I had the script on my "app.html". So with the first point(mentioned above) I never had issues, the popup always triggers, however ... with the second, the content that supposed to load with the div on the "cookie-policy" sometimes load, sometimes doesn't and mainly load when I refresh the page, so my question is if it is  something related to the ssr or is something else? and why is not happening with the popup?

So I went around the docs, about how to handle scripts on Nuxt, and based in what I have read, this script only may run on the client side, so to test it I changed my script so it runs under the plugins folder and with the extension .client, so is running on the client side, however now I am running in my second inquiry... can I run this script on the server side? (when they don't offer any dependency or module). Just thinking that if I make run this script on client and server, and after that I still have the same behaviour, then I need to look in some other possibility. Also I need to say the first possibility or first thing that came to my mind was that the script might be executing before, so by example I placed the "defer" attribute (just in case) on the script, but nothing changed.

So this is how my actual client plugin looks like:

```
export default () => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://provider.website.com/banner.js'
    script.setAttribute('data-cookiefirst-key', "xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx")
    document.head.appendChild(script)
}
```

Also, this is my nuxt.config.js.

```
  target: 'server',
  ssr: true,
  pageTransition: 'page',
  head: {
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
  },

  css: [
    '~/assets/sass/main',
  ],

  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/vue-animate-onscroll',
    '~/plugins/cookiefirst.client.js',
  ],

  components: true,

  buildModules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/device',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    '@nuxtjs/toast',
    '@nuxtjs/axios'
  ],
  i18n: {
    lazy: true,
    strategy: 'prefix_except_default',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    langDir: 'locales/',
    locales: [
      {
        name: 'EN',
        code: 'en',
        file: 'en.js'
      }
    ],
    vueI18n: {
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
    },
    detectBrowserLanguage: false
  },
  toast: {
    position: 'top-center',
    duration: '1000',
    className: 'msg'
  },
  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    transpile: ['lottie-vuejs']
  },

}
```

which also leads me to my last question, I am a junior and as I explained at the beginning this is my first time working with Nuxt and ssr. One dev looked at the page, and he told me that this was not ssr, but he did not explained why. I followed the documentation and activated the ssr. I am using vercel, so added the [vercel builder](https://github.com/nuxt/vercel-builder), and changed my build commands. Did I still miss something?

and just in case if someone want to see it, this is my cookie page, which I am filtering based on the slug id. But in the CMS I only have literally the div with the id:

```
<template>
<section v-if="pageBySlug">

<b-row>
  <b-col  offset-lg="1">
  <h1>{{pageBySlug.title}}</h1>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
<b-row>
  <b-col offset-lg="1">
    <div v-html="pageBySlug.content"></div>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
</section>  
 
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default{
      computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      pages: "pages",
      appLocale: "appLocale"
    }),
    pageBySlug() {
      return this.pages.filter((a) => a.slug == this.$route.params.id)[0];
    },
  },
  head() {
    if(this.pageBySlug){
    return {
      title:  `${this.pageBySlug.title}`,
    };
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Sorry for the long read and thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure about this dev, but your app is SSR since you have `target: 'server'` + `ssr: true`... Also, disable the JS on the page? Do you see some content? BOOM, it's SSR (or SSG). The fact that your thing is using a CDN is annoying by itself. Still, you did great already! You don't really need to run that on the server-side, I don't see the benefit here (I may be wrong). I recommend using `mounted` + [template $refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to target your elements in your Vue app, indeed a `querySelector`

Comment: is annoying to use in the context of an SPA (Nuxt is basically SSR/SSG + an SPA). So, if you come back and forth, the `querySelector` will behave poorly. Inject the script once globally, then load it on this very specific page. Then, it comes down to inspecting the script itself and see how it behaves/it's methods etc. It's always a pain when using a CDN. It's not possible to use some other service, with a real NPM support? Here it's still feasible just more tricky.

Comment: @kissu thank you for the feedback, and it is a relieve, unfortunately the user is using this service for all his websites, so I have no choice. The use of a ref, can be a possible approach although means I will have to modify something in their script. Also it is possible to make this script run on the server side y type of technic? I have been searching but a similar case but no luck so far, and thank you again for the feedback :)

Comment: Is the script meant to run on the server? It does have a `document.querySelector` no? Then it's not compatible on the server. On top of that, I'm not sure what would be the benefit of running the script on the server-side since it's a cookie banner thing.

Answer (score 0):

For the cookie policy to render properly in SPA you can use the following according to the JS api docs

`Cookiefirst.renderEmbeds()`